# In node add, how to upload file using image from clipboard

Tags: 7, nodes, javascript, blocks, files

How can I paste image from clipboard and save into image_field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the [FileField Sources](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_sources) module. It provides quite a few additional options to upload files.

> - Re-use files by an auto-complete textfield
> - Attach server-side files uploaded via FTP
> - Transfer files from a remote server (cURL required)
> - **Paste a file directly from the clipboard (Drupal 7 only)**
> - Select existing files through the IMCE file browser

Comment: works fine, tks